# Phonegap 1.5 - exit app

Tags: android, cordova

I'm new to developing phonegap apps and I have a problem:
I want the app to exit when a user... exists the app.

That doesn't happen with phonegap. When a user clicks the home button, the app stay paused and if the user enters the app again, the app stops working.

Any sugestions on how can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Applications in Android don't necessarily "close" the way you might expect if you're coming from different environments (like Windows or MacOS).  They *do* "start", and you must at any time expect they might either "restart" or "resume".

Here are some good links on "Android Activity Lifecycle"

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html

Here's a really, really good article that puts the issue in better perspective:

http://geekfor.me/faq/you-shouldnt-be-using-a-task-killer-with-android/

IMHO....

Answer (score 0):

did you try:

```
document.addEventListener("backbutton", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    navigator.app.exitApp();
}, false);
```